# Relation of the Lorentz group to $O(1,3)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be an element of the Lorentz group. It satisfies the identity:$${\Lambda}^T\eta\Lambda=\eta$$ where $\eta$ is the Minkowskii metric. Hence by the usual definition of orthogonality, $\Lambda$ is not an orthogonal matrix. Then how do you prove that it belongs to $O(1,3)$?

Comment: This is the definition of the group $O(1,3)$, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What are you taking to be the definition of $O(1,3)$?

Comment: If A$\in$O(1,3) then $A^TA=1$...I took this as my definition of O(1,3), but I guess it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonality here means preserving the the quadratic form $(ct, {\bf x}) \mapsto c^2t^2 - {\bf x}^T {\bf x} = x^\alpha \eta_{\alpha\beta}x^{\beta}$, hence the notation $O(1, 3)$.

The '*special*' comes from the fact that if $\Lambda \in O(1,3)$ then

$$
\Lambda ^T \eta \Lambda = \eta ~~~\Rightarrow |\Lambda|^2 = \pm 1
$$

So its determinant can be either $+1$ or $-1$. If you consider only transformations with $|\Lambda | = +1$ then you will get the *special generalized orthogonal group* $SO(1,3)$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Just one small thing, doesn't orthogonal mean $A^TA=1$?

Comment: Also, will matrix multiplication and matrix inverse carry the same meaning or do we need to define them accordingly?

Comment: @SounakSinha Orthogonal means a transformation that preserves some notion of distance. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is equivalent to say $A^TA = 1$, but you are not working in that space anymore. And yes, matrix operations work the same